# Combining if/else with variables in find command in bash script

Tags: bash, find

I am writing a script that prompts for user inputs and then runs a find command.

What I have works, but it feels like I have a lot of duplicated code due to the if / else structure.  Is it possible to have inline `if` statement?

So, instead of this kind of thing:

```
if [[ $depth_boolean == y ]] || [[ $depth_boolean == yes ]]
    then
        if [[ $symlink_boolean == y ]] || [[ $symlink_boolean == yes ]]
        then
            find -L $location -maxdepth $depth -readable -iname "$query" -$find_type $find_type_option -$find_action
        else
            find $location -maxdepth $depth -readable -iname "$query" -$find_type $find_type_option -$find_action
        fi
    else
        if [[ $symlink_boolean == y ]] || [[ $symlink_boolean == yes ]]
        then
            find -L $location -readable -iname "$query" -$find_type $find_type_option -$find_action
        else
            find $location -readable -iname "$query" -$find_type $find_type_option -$find_action
        fi
    fi
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
find if [ $symlink_boolean == y ]; then echo "-L";
   fi $location if [ $symlink_boolean == y ]; then 
   echo "-maxdepth $depth"; fi -readable -iname "$query" 
   -$find_type $find_type_option -$find_action
```

The above doesn't work, but wondering if it is possible?

Comment: Related - [How can I expand a quoted variable to nothing if it's empty?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/415990/100397)

Comment: Related: [But what if …?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408#286350 "Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can deal with the symlink with a simple variable:

```
symlink_flag=
if [[ $symlink_boolean == y ]]; then
    symlink_flag=-L
fi
find $symlink_flag "$location" -maxdepth "$depth" -readable ...
```

Note that `$symlink_flag` is unquoted here, so if empty, it disappears. The value it has doesn't contain any wildcards or default `IFS` characters, so not quoting it doesn't cause any harm. The other variables should be quoted, since e.g. the location might well contain whitespace.

For the depth part, your best bet is to build the command line in an array:

```
arguments=()
if [[ $symlink_boolean == y ]]; then
    arguments+=(-L)
fi
arguments+=("$location")
if [[ $depth_boolean == y ]]; then
    arguments+=(-maxdepth "$depth")
fi
find "${arguments[@]}" -readable -iname ...
```

You can put the nonchanging options on the `find` command line as above, or just unconditionally append them to the array and just run `find "${arguments[@]}"`.

See also:

- [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946/170373)
- [Word Splitting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) in [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide)
- [BashFAQ/050 or "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

---

Technically, you can also do what you propose with command substitution:

```
find $(if [[ $symlink_boolean == y ]]; then printf %s -L; fi) "$location"
    $(if [[ $depth_boolean == y ]]; then echo -maxdepth $maxdepth; fi) ...
```

Though in general this is not optimal, the only way to produce multiple words from the command substitution is to have them space-separated and then split, but that again doesn't work well if there are words within that should contain whitespace. `-maxdepth N` should work, though.

---

As a side note, you can condense the conditions a bit by using e.g. `[[ $symlink_boolean == [Yy]* ]]`. It would check if the variable starts with a `Y` or a `y`. (If you don't mind stuff like `YEAAHHH` also being truthy values.) Use the regex match `[[ $symlink_boolean =~ ^(y|yes)$ ]]` or `case $symlink_boolean in y|yes) echo "true";; esac` to just allow the two values.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help.  I've changed it up to build the command line into an array first as you suggested.  Thanks for the info about conditions too.